# Why LocalDate format changed when I transform entity to Json?

Tags: java, localdate, httpentity

My objective is to store dates into a database. To do this app I use Springboot, JPA, H2, ...

I use `LocalDate` and the format wished is `yyyy-MM-dd`.

**Entity**

```
@Entity
public class MyObject {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private LocalDate startdate;
    private LocalDate enddate;

    public MyObject() {}

    public MyObject(LocalDate enddate) {
        this.startdate = LocalDate.now();
        this.enddate = enddate;
    }

    ...
}
```

**Main**

```
private DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
MyObject myObject = new MyObject(LocalDate.parse("2019-03-01", formatter));
myObject.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
myObjectResource.save(myObject);

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
System.out.println(myObject.getStartdate()); // 2019-02-23
System.out.println(myObject.getEnddate()); // 2019-03-01
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(this.toJsonString(myObject), headers);
System.out.println(entity.toString()); // <{"id":"ba6649e4-6e65-4f54-8f1a-f8fc7143b05a","startdate":{"year":2019,"month":"FEBRUARY","dayOfMonth":23,"dayOfWeek":"SATURDAY","era":"CE","dayOfYear":54,"leapYear":false,"monthValue":2,"chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"}},"enddate":{"year":2019,"month":"MARCH","dayOfMonth":1,"dayOfWeek":"FRIDAY","era":"CE","dayOfYear":60,"leapYear":false,"monthValue":3,"chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"}}},[Content-Type:"application/json"]>

private String toJsonString(Object o) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    return om.writeValueAsString(o);
}
```

Can you help me to understand why dates in `entity.toString()` are not the same as before with `getMethods()` ?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Because Jackson doesn't know how else to format and parse LocalDate unless you add a module to do so. https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime

Comment: One option is that you can store the date as a string in your database, but by this, you'll lose the capability to perform operations on the date. However, you'll have to convert date back to localDate object to perform these operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LocalDate.parse` returns a new `LocalDate` object. The formatting options specified in the `DateTimeFormatter` get lost aftwerward.

`Jackson` (the `JSON` library you're using) doesn't know how you previously "formatted" the `LocalDate`, so it uses its own formatting.

You can register the `JavaTimeModule`

```
final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

Or you can provide your custom `JsonSerializer<T>`.

Comment: So used `LocalDate` is not the good choice? Used `Date` is a better idea?

Comment: @N.Lamblin continue using the new Java 8 API (Date should never be used again), but choose one of the alternatives I provided above.

Comment: No, not at all. Date is basically deprecated. Both don't have a format. A Date is just a number of milliseconds. a LocalDate i just a year, a month and a day. **You** choose which format to use when parsing a String to a Date or LocalDate, and when transforming a LocalDate or a Date to a String.

Comment: @LppEdd thanks a lot! However the Jackson documentation suggests using `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule` because `JSR310Module()` is deprecated.